# versioning of nuget / nuspec files

Tags: nuget, version

I have seen that nuget/microsoft itself uses a strange versioning strategy, see below.

2.14.0 and 2.14.0-rtm-832 are detected as the same version. In my opinion it should be 2.14.0 vs 2.14.0.832-rtm to get different version for prerelease.

Am I wrong?

https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.Core/2.14.0

Version Downloads   Last updated

NuGet.Core 2.14.0 (this version)    6,243   Wednesday, December 14, 2016

NuGet.Core 2.14.0-rtm-832   927 Monday, November 21, 2016

NuGet.Core 2.13.0   214 Wednesday, December 14, 2016

NuGet.Core 2.13.0-rc1-final 3,017   Thursday, August 11, 2016

NuGet.Core 2.12.0   41,256  Friday, July 29, 2016

NuGet.Core 2.12.0-rtm-815   989 Monday, June 27, 2016

NuGet.Core 2.11.1   40,678  Monday, April 25, 2016

NuGet.Core 2.10.1   51,860  Tuesday, December 1, 2015

Comment: "2.14.0 and 2.14.0-rtm-832 are detected as the same version"  are you sure? See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/prerelease-packages)

Comment: i created a nuspec file with dependecy version 2.14.0 in it, and when i try to download it with nuget.core, with prerelease packages enabled, it looks for 2.14.0-rtm-832. i only noticed it because we are hosting our packages on an own server and at startup this one resolves the dependencys and download the referenced packages. so the rtm-package is not on the server.

Comment: Show your package.config.